# Image View Not Scaling Between Different Devices

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-drawable

My activity is structured as follows:

A recycle view that is populated with an adapter and a CardView Layout.

The CardView is comprised of a constraint layout that contains an image and two text boxes.

The Image is set to a drawable that is asynchronously loaded from a URL.

Here is some code:

**Image Loading:**

```
  try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
        Drawable temp = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300, 300, true));
        return temp;
      }
 catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }

 This is called later in a different function where vh is the ViewHolder:
   vh.imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

**CardView XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:contentPadding="16dp" >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/playlist_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/playlist_name"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
etc...
```

**RecyclerView XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PlaylistChoose">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/playlist_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="auto"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/custom_playlist_view" >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Currently when I run this code on a Virtual Device the Image appears fine, However when I ran the app on a Galaxy S7 Edge the Images appeared extremely small. I then tried increasing the Height and Width in `Drawable temp = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300, 300, true));` from 300 to about 1400 and the app then ran fine on the S7 But the virtual device now displayed the images as absurdly large. I'm a bit confused since the Image is inside a constraint layout that is set to wrap content and the content size is the same for both phones, So I don't understand why the actual size would differ... Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated :)

Some pictures:

AVD 1400 : https://gyazo.com/1c4ab4ffb9266e191357dd3e0dcd2f5c

S7 1400: https://gyazo.com/fd87f094bf7f23933543369b206b794a

AVD 300: https://gyazo.com/d5c23c9372bc0c1838866452a24af06f

S7 300: https://gyazo.com/a9084b77d3efdd87cea9e53344c7b169

Comment: Hardcoding Image pixel size is not a good idea ..  Simply Use a fix size `ImageView` in `dp` and use some library to download the image for you efficiently [may be this one](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)..

Comment: @ADM Im using the library and it loads the images, I didn't really understand what you meant though with using a fix size in dp, So it loads the images at an extremely large size. Could you further elaborate what exactly you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It was due to a combination of @ADM's suggestion to use the glide library together with @Tamir Abutbul's Scale and Constraint Percent suggestion that my images now load correctly :)

XML:

```
<ImageView
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"

                android:id="@+id/playlist_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/playlist_name"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Glide Code:

```
 Glide.with(context).load(url).into(vh.imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

*I'm a bit confused since the Image is inside a constraint layout that is set to wrap content and the content size is the same for both phones*

The content may be the same for different phones but because different phone got different screen sizes while using `wrap_content` on your `ImageView` it won't look the same on all devices.

**How to fix:**

With `ConstraintLayout` you will want to do something like this:

**Use this as your Image view:**

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_image" />
```

Now, this will be **exactly** 25% in the width and height of its parent.

**You can change the size of the image if you want, just change:**

```
   app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
   app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, The images still appear small, I don't think its a problem with the ImageView since there's a default Image that's set as the source of the image view in the xml (before I get the url image), and the default image loads fine on both the avd and the s7.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add scaleType and adjustment of view bounds inside your ImageView

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/playlist_image"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/playlist_name"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
   app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use

```
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"

Answer (score 0):

```
     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playlist_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/playlist_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```